# Need help in listing all data retrieve from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, html, visual-studio-2010, responsive-design

I'm new to asp .net web application.

Is it possible to retrieve data from Microsoft SQL Server and preview it in a menu drop down list where the data are already flter by alphabetical? For example when I click the menu "A", it will drop down menu and show the option I have for the menu "A".

Any one that done it before and can provide me the link to make it happen? If possible, the design is responsive design .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a categories like This you can save them in database

```
enum MenuCategory { Cata = 1, Catb = 2 };
```

Add a menu control:

```
var menu1 = new Menu() { ID = "TestMenu" };
```

now we add first level of menu that is our category:

```
var cat = MenuCategory.Cata;
var menuItem = new MenuItem(cat.ToString(), cat.ToString());
menu1.Items.Add(menuItem);
```

now adding sublevel for this category. Get data from database by your method

```
var catItems = new DAL.Repositories.MenuRepository().GetAMenutblByCategory(Convert.ToInt16(cat));
```

now for each data that you retrieve from database add a menuitem:

```
foreach (var menutbl in catItems)
{
    var childmenuItem = new MenuItem(menutbl.MenuValue, menutbl.MenuId.ToString(), "", menutbl.NavigationUrl);
    menu1.FindItem(cat.ToString()).ChildItems.Add(childmenuItem);
}
```

You should do this for all of your category, And finally add your menu to page.

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(menu1);
```

if you are doing this on pageload please be sure checkin `!ispostback`

```
new MenuItem(strin text,string value, string imageurl,string navigationurl)
```